# Не понимаю как устранить проблему?

Tags: python

```py
import config
import logging

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher,executor, types


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


bot = Bot(token=config.TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.massage_handler()
#15#



async def echo(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(message.text)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

```
C:\Users\j\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/j/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/BOT/bot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\j\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\BOT\bot.py", line 15, in <module>
    async def echo(message: types.Message):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: полагаю, это потому что вместо комментария должна быть функция

Answer (score 1):

Вы написали `@dp.massage_handler()` , а нужно `@dp.message_handler()` *('ma' - > 'me')*